# Is it correct to say "big brother"?

Tags: adjectives

[Source](https://youtu.be/ZLOzErbOVdc?t=1060)

In the video, [at 17:40](https://youtu.be/ZLOzErbOVdc?t=1060), a guy says:

> I wasn't much of a big brother.

Isn't it incorrect to say? I think it should be elder brother.

Comment: It means "older" informally, you can look it up in Oxford Dictionary.

Comment: "Big" and "elder" are not necessarily interchangeable. "Big" can refer to size as well as age. You are more likely to refer to an elder brother when there is a younger brother rather than a sister. "Big brother" in this context conveys a sense of caring that is absent with "elder brother". A sister might well refer to "my big brother" even though she was older.

Comment: When I run to this phrase (big brother) it almost always means an older  (or elder) brother. It may also have the meaning of an government that spies on its population (from the book '1984') but it rarely means a larger (in size) but younger brother. Using the phrase big brother (or sister) is often made in relation to a little brother (or sister).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a correct (and common) usage.

At least throughout America, native speakers tend to say "big brother" to mean "elder brother". (I would suggest that "big brother" is far more common than "older brother" which is more common than "elder brother", all meaning the same thing.)

See:
https://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=elder%20brother,big%20brother

[not that this is the best proof but it's something]

Personal theory: "elder" is too close to "elderly", so people don't like to use it. Your "elderly brother" sounds like he's 70 years old or more. Your "big brother" is older than you without being close to sounding like "elderly". People would know what you meant if you said "elder brother" but it's not the common way to say it.

"Big brother" seems like it should refer to size, and sometimes people use it that way, but it almost always means older (even when the older brother is physically smaller).

*[amusing not-really-related side note: "big brother" is also an idiom for the government, especially a government that is seen as meddlesome, though clearly that's not what the speaker intends here]*